# Javers - Disable automatic SQL schema creation, user not granted DDL privileges

Tags: javers

I am using javers-persistence-sql version 3.7.9

I launched the sql script for table creation manually

I need to disable the ddl auto create because the schema that the application uses does not have grants for DDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is waiting for a contributor since May 2017

https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/542

Consider contributing a PR

Comment: Hi Bartek , 
I actually implemented a way to avoid  ddl creation by extending JaversSqlRepository and overriding  ensureSchema(), but to do it I extended other classes(JsonConverter and TableNameProvider) redefining them in org.javers package. 
If you have a better solution I will be happy to implement and commit it.